# Is there a way to change part of the title to another font style or set a custom title format in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to change one word of the title so it looks like this:

**Example title with *italic* word**

but currently the only thing I can get is all text bold or all text italic.

I need to put scientific names in italics and keep the whole title in bold.

Chart.js [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html) on titles doesn't provide a way to set a custom format or even provide an array of fontStyles to set different lines with diferent styles, and using html or markdown doesn't work either, it just takes the string as it is.

I want to know if there is a way to do this via a callback or even a plugin, because so far I haven't found any of those.

Example of what doesn't work: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/parrawk/pen/GRoeWEr)

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text:
            'Example <i>title<i> for *italic* word',
        fontSize: 18, //Tamaño de letra del titulo
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload an example in codesandbox.io ?

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian I hope it helps to convey what I'mtrying to do but it's just the basic way of setting titles.

Answer (score 1):

As of Chart.js v3, you can now add different styles for the `title` and `subtitle` of the chart. So while you wouldn't be able to italicize just one word, you could italicize just the subtitle:

```
plugins: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Example Title'
  },
  subtitle: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Example Italic Subtitle',
    font: {
      style: 'italic'
    }
  }
},
```

The full options for `title` and `subtitle` can be found in the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the style of the title you need to use `fontStyle`, in this case inside your `options.title`:

```
 options: {
     title: {
       display: true,
        text: 'Example <i>title<i> for *italic* word',
        fontSize: 18, //Tamaño de letra del titulo
        fontStyle:"italic"
     },
  }
```

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: black;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <canvas
            id="myChart"
            width="1904"
            height="400"
            class="chartjs-render-monitor"
            style="display: block; width: 1904px; height: 400px;"
        >
        </canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily =
                'Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'; //Tipo de letra
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14; //Tamaño de letra global
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#fff'; //Color de letra

            var labels_1 = ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test'];

            var data_1 = [10, 12, 25, 35];

            var colors = [
                'rgba(44,127,184, 1)'
            ];

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                    labels: labels_1,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: '',
                            data: data_1,
                            backgroundColor: colors[0],
                            borderColor: colors[0],
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            fill: false,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text:
                            'title in italic',
                        fontSize: 18, //Tamaño de letra del titulo,
                        fontStyle:"italic"
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 10,
                            right: 10,
                        },
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                var title =
                                    data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                                title = title.toString();
                                title = title.split(',');
                                title = title.join('\n');
                                return title;
                            },
                            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                var value =
                                    data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                value = value.toString();
                                value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                                value = value.join(',');
                                return value;
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                display: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                },
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: 'No. de focos',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        xAxes: [
                            {
                                display: false,
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                },
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: 'País',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                },
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to do is just to set one or two words or even a new line of text in italic, withouth making the whole title italics and keeping everything in bold.